# How to convert long data frame to igraph object

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data frame in this format:

```
                   doc_id                               doc_uni
1: S0100-879X1998000800006               University of Gorakhpur
2: S0100-879X1998000800011     Universidade Estadual de Londrina
3: S0100-879X1998000800005 Ivano-Frankivsk State Medical Academy
4: S0100-879X1998000800005        Southern Sea Biology Institute
5: S0100-879X1998000800005                   Carleton University
```

In which `doc_id` represents a published paper and `doc_uni` the university where the author(s) are from. My goal is to analyze this data as a social network.

From this small sample, I would create this graph object:

```
uni1 | uni2
University of Gorakhpur | NA
Universidade Estadual de Londrina | NA
Ivano-Frankivsk State Medical Academy | Southern Sea Biology Institute
Ivano-Frankivsk State Medical Academy | Carleton University
Southern Sea Biology Institute | Carleton University
```

I have tried writing a for loop to accomplish this task but my dataset has 602k rows so it was pretty inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you just have two vertex types, papers and universities?

Comment: @Mark can you please tell me how to do itor maybe provide a small example?